# What does it mean for a prime ideal to split completely?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303131/extension-mathbbq-sqrt-5-i-mathbbq-sqrt-5-splitting). What does it mean for a prime ideal to split completely?

Answer (score 4):

If $L/K$ is a field extension and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime of $K$, then in $L$ we have
$$\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L = \prod_{i=1}^g \mathfrak{P}_i^{e_i}$$
where the $\mathfrak{P}_i$ are primes of $\mathcal{O}_L$ and $e_i\ge 1$ are integers. $\mathfrak{p}$ is totally split if all of the $e_i=1$ and if, further, for each $\mathfrak{P}_i$, the residue field degree
$$f_i = [\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{P}_i : \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}] = 1.$$
Note that this means that $g = [L:K]$.

Comment: Don't you mean $f_i = [\mathcal{O}_?/\mathfrak{B}_i : \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}] = 1$...?

Comment: @user141494 thanks.